# loadFromJSON fabric.js image breaks JSON Data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, fabricjs

I am trying to run this function using fabric.js cardCanvas.loadFromJSON(frontPreviewData);

If I have an image in the JSON data it eats the JSON and shows 0 objects.  Below are links to what the JSON looks like before and after the loadFromJSON takes place.  If the JSON data does not have the image file inserted it works fine.  I tried turning off and on crossOrigin and it doesn't make a difference.

[Before loadFromJSON and JSON.stringify](http://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=2a8a6190795a591cf48b7f9a9cb84fe5)

[After loadFromJSON and JSON.stringify](http://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=cd1939850f3f16aa1aa6650018ba8653)